# what happens when a class object is used as an index for an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading

Say we have a class:

```
class A {
  private:
      int index;
  public:
  // related overloaded functions and other stuffs
};
```

now say we use it as an index in array that expects int.

```
A in;
Z z = arr[in]; // arr is of some type Z.
```

I want to ask when 'in' is used in 'in', what functions (say copy constructor or overloaded assignment operator) is called or object is directly typecast here.

What will be the difference if class is like this

```
class A {
  private:
    int index1;
    int index2;
  public:
 // related overloaded functions and other stuffs
};
```

Comment: Post the complete definition of `A`, please. Does it perhaps have a conversion operator to an integral type?

Comment: no I have not made any conversion operator. just assignment operator and copy constructor. I dont even know about conversion operator.

Comment: Without a conversion operator this should not even compile, if you do have a compiling example, please post it as an http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `A` class must have an `operator int` or `operator size_t` perhaps, defined. That operator is used to convert an instance of that class into an integral type, at which point regular array access takes place. Example:

```
class A {

public:

    operator int() const;
};

class IN {

public:

};

int main()
{
    A a;

    IN in[4];

    in[a];
}
```

Comment: Thanks sam, that was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about overloading int(). Now I will test it thanks.